# tcolorbox: theorem numbering in the margin is too close to text

Tags: numbering, margins, theorems, tcolorbox

I'm using `tcolorbox` to draw boxes around my theorems. This package also has the option of puting the theorem numbers in the margin as you can see in my MWE below; see page 342 of [the manual](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for more details.

The problem is that, even with a pretty vanilla setup as in my example, the numbering of the theorem overlaps with the box. I could not find an option for adjusting this, but I'm sure there must be something.

Does anybody know how to place the theorem number farther from the theorem box?

Please note that I would like to use `tcolorbox`, so please don't suggest a solution for a similar effect using a different package.

**EDIT:** In case I was not very clear, I need the numbering to be inside the margin, outside the box, and left from the box. I do not ask to put the number back in the box, this could simply be done by removing the `margin apart` style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]%
{theorem} % \begin..
{Theorem} % Title
{theorem style = margin apart, % Style
 colback=white,
 colframe=lightgray,
 coltitle=black}
{theo} % label prefix; cite as ``theo:yourlabel''

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\begin{theorem}{The title}{mylabel}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried adding something like "left=-2mm", but this moves all the text, including the contents and the titles, so it's not good. I'd like the titles and contents of the theorem to remain where they are, while the number shifts to the left.

Comment: Using the numbers outside in the margin does not really look nice, regardless whether this is done with `tcolorbox` or anything else

Comment: I know, but I need to do it anyway

Comment: I'll be writing a huge thesis with a gazillion of numbered stuff, that my supervisor will be reading in print, not as a pdf. That will make his life much easier, when I am to print the final draft, I'll probably switch back to normal numbering..

Comment: sigh, supervisors ....

Comment: Hehe, he didn't ask me to do it though so it's not a big deal

Comment: See my update, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with a `theorem name` style and shifting a `overlay` out of the box with `overlay={\node[...]}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]%
{theorem} % \begin..
{Theorem} % Title
{%theorem style = margin apart, % Style
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=lightgray,
  theorem name,
  coltitle=black,%
  overlay={\node[xshift=-20pt] (A) at (title.west) {\bfseries \thetcbcounter};},
  left=2mm,
  }
{theo} % label prefix; cite as ``theo:yourlabel''

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\begin{theorem}{The title}{mylabel}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is entirely different from what I'm looking for. I would like the numbers to be inside the margin, that is, outside the box and left from the box, while the title remains where it is.

Comment: @geo909: Well, use some `lefttitle=` with negative value then, but actually, this does not really look nice

Comment: As I was saying, this will cause the whole title to shift, so the numbers *and* the "Theorem (The title)". I only want the numbers to be in the margin and the title to remain where it is.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Christian's solution, I've introduced a magic number as `left skip` and the result looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]%
{theorem} % \begin..
{Theorem} % Title
{%theorem style = margin apart, % Style
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=lightgray,
  theorem name,
  coltitle=black,%
  overlay={\node[xshift=-20pt] (A) at (title.west) {\bfseries \thetcbcounter};},
  left=2mm,
%  show bounding box,
%  width=\linewidth,
  left skip=32pt
  }
{theo} % label prefix; cite as ``theo:yourlabel''

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}{The title}{mylabel}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice too (+1) -- The value of `32pt` is the width of `1.1.1`, I assume?

Comment: It's supposed to be, but I fond it by trial and error.